# Ranking observations based

Tags: r, logistic

I have observations categorized into one of 5 categorical variables, and each observation also has a probability of occurrence, as computed through logistic regression. 
Here's how the distribution of each categorical variable and probabilities look like.

```
$`NA`
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
     NA      NA      NA     NaN      NA      NA  518695 

$`0`
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.4718  0.7192  0.8365  0.8044  0.9089  0.9626 

$`1`
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.4718  0.7588  0.8488  0.8253  0.9089  0.9534 

$`2`
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.4718  0.8998  0.9344  0.9193  0.9573  0.9847 

$`3`
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.4718  0.9279  0.9406  0.9333  0.9658  0.9878 

$`4`
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.4718  0.9109  0.9344  0.9207  0.9611  0.9878
```

Currently, I have assigned each categorical variable a number equal to `x*100`, where x is a variable. So, the range is from 0 to 400. Similarly, I have divided probabilities into deciles, and multiplied (`decile -1` )by 10. This leads to overall range from 0 to 490. Is this a good way to categorize observations? Are there any other better ways to rank observations when we have multiple criteria? I'd appreciate any thoughts. I searched on StackExchange and found a lot of questions on this topic, but I couldn't find any answer.